# Listing Child Pages in Random order

Tags: child-pages, wp-list-pages, get-children

I am currently using a Plug-in that creates a "silo" structure for my website. It creates a sidebar with a list of the Parent page followed by the Child Pages. It only allows me to show the Child pages in the order that they were created. I would like to have the child pages listed in random order, Is this a possibility?

Example:

```
Pool Removal Contractors
-Alabama
-Arizona
-Arkansas
```

I found the following code here:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )    
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' .$post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

    if ( $childpages ) {    
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sort_column` parameter of [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) does allow items to be returned in random order using the `rand` option.

> **sort_column**
>   *(string)* Comma-separated list of column names to sort the pages by. Accepts 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_title', 'post_name',
>   'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'menu_order', 'post_parent',
>   'ID', **'rand'**, or 'comment_count'. Default 'post_title'.

```
add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 
    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=rand&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    } else {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=rand&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    }

    if ( $childpages ) {    
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}
```